# Using a progressBar in a listview item

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, progress-bar

I have this listview and it's coded in a fragment class. When selecting a listview item it goes to another fragment and displays the details . But it takes several seconds to load the data because the data i display is using AsyncTask,so it takes some time to get data from the JSON and display .  So i need to use a progressBar when an item is clicked in the listview and  it should close when the data is ready to display. How can i do this? I referred several tutorials and tried many of them. But i couldn't accomplish what i'm looking for.Hope some of you can help me.

NewsFragment class

```
private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> News;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();


        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id){ 


                   android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new NewsDetailFragment();
                   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit(); 

                }
              });

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }




public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            News = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();
            return null;
        } 

        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setNewsDescription(News);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(News, activity,Element.NEWS_LIST.getType());

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

}
```

NewsDetailFragment

```
public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private View view1;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();


        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }



public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();

            return null;

        } 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

NewsList layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/grey"
     >


    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/listview" >

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"


        /> 


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <!--  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/news_title"
        android:textSize="15dp" />   -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

NewsFragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@color/grey" >


  <!--  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"/>   --> 

        <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:dividerHeight="10dp"
              android:layout_margin="6dp">
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ProgressBar` to your NewsFragment layout:

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Then in `onItemClick` method change it's visibility to true `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show it and change it's visibility to false to hide it `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask.

Comment: i get this error

The method setVisibility(int) is undefined for the type ProgressDialog

Comment: The method `setVisibility(int)` is defined for every `View` and `ProgessBar` is a subclass of `View`. Note this is `ProgressBar` class not `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: application crashes :(

Comment: What is your output of Logcat? If you want to stick with using `ProgressDialog` simply call `ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait ...", "Some message to user...", false)` in `onItemClick` and `progressDialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask. However this limits you to displaying `ProgressBar` on center of the screen while my first method gives you ability to put it whereever you want. You should also put code associated with going to detail fragment in `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask not in `onItemClick` method.

Comment: I get a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You have to be more specific and tell me in which line of code you get exception. You're now using ProgessBar or ProgressDialog?

Comment: I'm using progessBar.  i get the errors where i've put 
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
and
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Ok, so you probably forget to get a reference to ProgressBar from XML with `findViewById` method in `onCreateView` method of NewsFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it now. I modified my 2nd fragment like this.  When an item in the listview is clicked it goes to my second class.So i added a progressBar to my second class and it worked!

```
public class NewsDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private View view1;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> newsdetail;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();


        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        view1 = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsDetailFragment.this.getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading News");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }



public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            newsdetail = JSONServices.getNewsDescription();

            return null;

        } 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(newsdetail);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(newsdetail, activity,Element.NEWS_DETAIL.getType());

            ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) view1).setAdapter(adapter);

            dialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

}
```